# Image not shown on Emulator/Device? Eclipse Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, imageview

I made multiple apps and never got stuck on this but,
I can't see any image.

In eclipse i used the imageview, and nothing when running the app in the emulator or on my Xperia Z.

Even tried just setting it as **android:background**. Didn't work either..
Also tried to change in the ImageView the src line to background and didn't work either. Also tried using a different image and nothing. The only image that works is the ic_launcher.

By the way i also deleted the whole project on eclipse and recreating it + reinstalling eclipse multiple times.
Both didn't work!

So if anyone has a idea i would love to hear it because this really sucks.

> Splash Activity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Splash" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/sl" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> Splash.java

```
package com.skatelogic;

import com.skatelogic.Main;
import com.skatelogic.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;

public class Splash extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        Thread splash_screen = new Thread(){

            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(2000);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally{
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main.class));
                    finish();
                }
            }

        };
        splash_screen.start();

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.splash, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Make sure naming convention is correct and format. Save int the drawable folder. if all of that is true try project-clean project

Comment: are you trying to make a splash screen ? if yes did you add your activity as launcher activity in manifest file ?

Comment: Already did that. The splash screen works but the images are just not shown. Only that, every activity works perfect except for the images

Answer (score 0):

in the xml file instead of background put this line

```
<ImageView
   ....
   ....
    android:src="@drawable/sl" />
```

where s1 is your image file in **png format**

Answer (score 0):

Where is your main class? I can't see any statement where you show your picture. Just saving it onto the drawable file will not do. You need to even give a syntax for it.

```
im=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
im.setImageResource(R.drawable.f1);
```